# How to get milliseconds in midifile?

Tags: c#, midi

I'm using a library called DryWetMidi.

I want to load a MIDI file and get the milliseconds from the start of every note.

My approach of importing the notes and accessing the .Time seems to be the time calculated from the ticks in the MIDI itself. Is it possible to convert this to milliseconds?

Comment: Please read the docs on the library - https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/high-level-managing/Time-and-length.html. To get metric time of a note use this: `var metricTime = note.TimeAs<MetricTimeSpan>(tempoMap);`